# php max_input_time -1 meaning: php.ini vs php documentation?

Tags: php

I am about to update the max_input_time on a server to point to max_execution_time and wondered which definition of -1 is correct?

Here's the php.ini definition:

> ; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
>   ; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)

Here's the php documentation: (http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php)

> The default setting is -1, which means that max_execution_time is used
>   instead. Set to 0 to allow unlimited time.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer/theory.

Setting the max_input_time to -1 does allow it to be infinite.
However, that infinite time is constrained by the max_execution_time setting.

So we end up with...

1. Post/Get can process for an infinite amount of time (max_input_time = -1).
2. The PHP script itself can run for 60 seconds (max_execution_time = 60).
3. Therefore, max_input_time can only run for at most 60 seconds until the script gets killed.